# how to extract and plot the immediate neighbors (and the neighbors of neighbors) in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, networkx

Consider the following example

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(
    [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('E', 'C'),
     ('H', 'C'), ('Y', 'I')])

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

I would like to extract and plot the subgraphs containing 'A' and all of neighbors, then all the neighbors of the neighbors, and so on `n` times (obtaining n different charts, that is). To be clear: step 0 is the node `A` itself, step 1 is the network `B-A-C`, step 2 is the network `D-B-A-C-E-H` (`Y` and `I` have been removed because they are not neighbors of neighbors of `A`).

I have been unable to do so with `networkx`. Using `all_neighbors()` extracts all immediate neighbors (`B` and `C`) but somehow loses `A` in the process so the graph is incomplete.

```
zn = G.subgraph(nx.all_neighbors(G, 'A'))
nx.draw_networkx(zn)
```

[image]

What can be done here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nearest neighbour subgraphs are called ego-graphs in network analysis, available in networkx through `nx.ego_graph(G, source, distance)`.

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(
    [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('E', 'C'),
     ('H', 'C'), ('Y', 'I')])

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

max_distance = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, max_distance, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for distance, ax in zip(range(max_distance), axes):
    nx.draw_networkx(nx.ego_graph(G, "A", distance), pos=pos, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to build an [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)/[`union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) of all the [`descendants_at_distance`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.descendants_at_distance.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.descendants_at_distance):

```
des_atd = [
    des
    for i in range(len(G))
    if (des := nx.descendants_at_distance(G, "A", distance=i))
]

from itertools import accumulate

out = list(accumulate(des_atd, set.union))

# [{'A'}, {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H'}]
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: very nice, thanks! but how to plot the selected nodes while keeping the original structure of the network?

Comment: Can you precise which layout you're using or you're intending to use ? Also, side note, the draw you share in OP is not reproducible since you didn't provide a seed.

Comment: I am simply using draw_networkx(). the visual aspect is not important here. I am just asking how do you plot the subtree that you obtain in `out`? thanks!

Comment: To answer your last comment, [here](https://pastebin.com/Tr6Erp4A) is the code I used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a recursive approach could help you

```
zm = nx.Graph()

start = 'D'
def node_search(start,i):   
 y = 0
 while y < i:
    
    zn = G.subgraph(nx.all_neighbors(G, start)) 
    for node in zn:
        zm.add_edge(node, start)
        
        if zn.has_node(node):
            node_search(node,y)
        
    y = y + 1   


node_search(start,2)

zm.edges()
```

Starting from 'D' with 2 Steps i get as result:
EdgeView([('B', 'D'), ('B', 'A')])

Comment: If needed I can explain what I did further in my lunch break

Comment: I see. Thanks. So somehow one needs to "connect" the root node to its neighbors manually using all_neighbors? what is he purpose of the node_search call?

Comment: the first call done below? it marks the starting point

Comment: no the if clause, can you explain its logic?

Comment: the if clause makes sure that you dont iterate over a node that has already been processed. If you leave it out you will always go over all neighbours of the currently checked node. So you might also take a step back what isnt desired.